# want friend function in namespace, but not the whole class

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, friend

this is a follow-up question to [friend function within a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749311/friend-function-within-a-namespace)

If I want testFunc to be in namespace TestNamespace, but I don't want TestClass also in TestNamespace, how can I declare them?

1.This doesn't work ("expected unqualified-id before namespace" on line 2)

```
class TestClass {
namespace TestNamespace {
    friend void testFunc(TestClass &myObj);
};
}

namespace TestNamespace {
    void testFunc(TestClass &myObj);
}
```

2.But it complains that "TestNamespace::testFunc(...) should have been declared inside 'TestNamespace'" when I do this-

```
class TestClass {
friend void TestNamespace::testFunc(TestClass &myObj);

}

namespace TestNamespace {
    void testFunc(TestClass &myObj);
}
```

3.The above code is okay if I don't have the "TestNamespace::" in the friend function declaration on line 2, but I'm not sure if it then knows that TestNamespace::testFunc is a friend.

I don't know what's happening in any of these cases. Any insight would be much appreciated too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using forward declarations:

```
class TestClass;

namespace TestNamespace {
    void testFunc(TestClass &myObj);
}

class TestClass {
    friend void TestNamespace::testFunc(TestClass &myObj);
};
```

I don't know what "leda" was in your original example, but hopefully you can substitute whatever names you need given the above.

Comment: Thank you! Forward declarations are great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it simple:

```
class TestClass; // forward declaration

namespace TestNamespace {  // namespace body
    void testFunc(TestClass &myObj);  // passing by reference, ok!
}

class TestClass {
    friend void TestNamespace::testFunc(TestClass &myObj); // scoping with namespace
};
```

Remember, **namespace body can be only in global scope** (not inside class or function).